# Finding Current Win Streak Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I would like my spreadsheet to count the current win streak.

For example:
If DE match history looks like `W W W L W W` then I would like the current win streak to say `W2`. If DK match history looks like `L L W L L L` then I would like the current win streak to say `L3`.

Here is an example spreadsheet,
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NROEe3VOAXDDianHcLk3y6YSBLNGMAj3t9GC4WJDvwM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Tom's comments, this worked for me:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(JOIN("",D2:R2),"(L|W)*$") & LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(JOIN("",D2:R2),"(L*|W*)$"))
```

[image]

Comment: Neat. I wouldn't have known that this would grab a sequence containing just W or L, but not a mixture of both.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a regex to find consecutive W's or L's at the end of the list:

```
=iferror(regexextract(textjoin("",true,E2:2),"W+$"),regexextract(textjoin("",true,E2:2),"L+$"))
```

This formula will ignore any empty cells.

[image]

Or to put it in W2, L2 format:

```
=iferror("W"&len(regexextract(textjoin("",true,E2:2),"W+$")),"L"&len(regexextract(textjoin("",true,E2:2),"L+$")))
```